# Function to transpose a matrix in place

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have written the following function in C

```
double * transpose(double *M, int n) {
    double *T = (double *) malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
          T[i + (j * n)] = M[(i * n) + j];
      }
    }

    return T;
}
```

and I call it as such:

```
C = transpose(C, n);
```

where `C` was previously declared as

```
double *C = (double *) malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));
```

and then initialised with values.

How can I, instead of returning `T`, set my function type to void and then call the equivalent of `*M = *T` instead of my `return` statement. In other words, how can I call the function like:

```
transpose(C, n);
```

so that `*C` is pointing to the memory allocation created by `*T`?

EDIT:

As pointed out by wildplasser below, a more efficient way of transposing the matrix in place would be swapping the {i, j} pairs except along the diagonal.

Something along the lines of this:

```
void * transpose(double *M, int n) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            if (i != j) {
                double temp = M[i + (j * n)];
                M[i + (j * n)] = M[(i * n) + j];
                M[(i * n) + j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, calling this as

```
transpose(C, n);
```

does not allow `C` to keep it's transposition after the function. What am I doing wrong here?

Also GCC is giving me the warning

```
Utilities.c: In function 'transpose':
Utilities.c:34:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
```

I have defined my function as `void` in both the header and source file?

Comment: Swap the {i,j} <--> {j,i} values  (ecxept for the diagonal)

Comment: In your function you could allocate T, transpose C to T, copy T to C and free T afterwards

Comment: BTW, in `C = transpose(C, n);` you got a memory leak

Comment: @Amadeus How so? By not freeing `T` inside the function?

Comment: @wildplasser That is a better solution, please see the edit to my original question.

Comment: `void` is not `void *`, these are different things.

Comment: @n.m. My bad, didn't spot that.

Comment: You are swapping {2,3} with {3,2} (when i==2,j==3) and afterwards swapping {3,2} with {2,3} (when i==3,j==2). The net result is a no-op.

Comment: `for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {` -->>  `for (j = i+1; j < n; j++) {`   BTW:there are methods with a better locality of reference (if performance matters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void transpose(double *arr, size_t siz)
{

size_t ii,jj;

for(ii=0;ii<siz;ii++)  {
        for(jj=ii+1;jj<siz;jj++){
                double tmp;
                size_t aa,bb;

                aa = ii+ siz * jj;
                bb = jj+ siz * ii;
                tmp = arr[aa];
                arr[aa] = arr[bb];
                arr[bb] = tmp;
                }
        }
}
```

---

Don't worry about the`aa` and `bb` variables. Any decent compiler will optimize them away.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code has a memory leak.  You overwrite the previous value of `C` without ever freeing it.

To transpose in place, you need to just swap all the right indexes without swapping twice.  So it's like the same problem as reversing an array in place.

```
void transpose(double *M, int n) {
  int i, j;
  double temp;
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      temp = M[i + j * n];
      M[i + j * n] = M[j + i * n];
      M[j + i * n] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As pointed out in the comments above, I beliebe this what swap each pair of elements twice, thus cancelling each other out.

Comment: @KOB It does not. Notice we loop for i from 0 to n and for j from 0 to i (exclusive)? This means you'll never swap twice because j will always be less than i, so you will never loop over both elements (i, j) and (j, i), undoing a swap.

Comment: Sorry, I thought both i and j were looping 0 through n.

Answer (score -1):

```
void transpose(double **C, double *M, int n) {
    double *T = (double *) malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
          T[i + (j * n)] = M[(i * n) + j];
      }
    }

    *C = T;
}
```

And call your function like this :

```
transpose(&C, n);
```

As the comments suggest free the old C before to avoid memory leak

Comment: I was trying to get something along the lines of this working. And how do I then declare `C` and pass it into the function?

Comment: Don't forget to free the old C, else you will get a memory leak.

Comment: And, Memory leak?

Comment: And why exactly would anyone prefer this over the original function?

Comment: You cannot free the old C and **then** use it.

Comment: This is *not* in-place transpose. OP wants to change the contents of what `C` points to, not to make it point to a different place.